# Android: how to use Code to interface design pattern to have multiple implementations of network call libraries(Retrofit or volley)

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

I am learning design patterns from Head First Design Patterns and the first pattern i came across is to "Code to interface".Now i want to use that pattern in my android app.My app includes lots of api calls.I am using Retrofit for for network calls.So i have used that design pattern considering some scenario something like this:
1. Suppose in future i need to shift from Retrofit to volley or any other networking library.
2. So i created an interface with a method to getData from server and created a class which implements that interface.The implemented method includes the Retrofit code to getData from server.
3. Now in future if i want to use volley i'll create a new class implementing the interface and with volley code to retrieve data from server.
The code goes like this

**UPDATED**

Retrofit specific interface

```
public interface RetrofitApi {
    @GET
    Call<ResponseBody> getDataFromServer(@Url String url);
}
```

**UPDATED**

Interface

A generic interface to have multiple implementations of network calls Library(here i am using retrofit so I created a class NetworkCallsRetrofitImpl that implements this interface.If i want to switch to volley i would create another class with volley implementation and implement this interface)

```
public interface NetworkCallsApi {
    String getDataFromServer(Activity activity,String url,String Callback);
}
```

Retrofit Implementation

```
public class NetworkCallsRetrofitImpl implements NetworkCallsApi{

private Retrofit retrofit;

@Override
public String getDataFromServer(Activity activity, String url, String Callback) {

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(StringConstants.ROOT_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    RetrofitApi apiCalls = retrofit.create(RetrofitApi.class);

    Call<ResponseBody> call = apiCalls.getDataFromServer(url);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

            Method method = null;
            try {
                method = fragment.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(
                        Callback, new Class[]{String.class});
                method.invoke(fragment, response.body().string());
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
    return null;
}
}
```

ServiceCalls.java

```
public class ServiceCalls {

public static ServiceCalls serviceCalls;
public NetworkCallsApi networkCallsimpl;

public static ServiceCalls getInstance(){

    if(serviceCalls == null){
        serviceCalls = new ServiceCalls();
    }
    return serviceCalls;
}

public void setNetworkCallsimpl(NetworkCallsApi networkCallsimpl) {
    this.networkCallsimpl = networkCallsimpl;
}

public String getDataFromServer(Activity activity, String url, String callback){
    networkCallsimpl.getDataFromServer(activity,url,callback);
    return null;
}
}
```

MainFragment Code:

```
public class StatusFragment extends Fragment {    

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Setting the implementation
    ServiceCalls.getInstance().setNetworkCallsimpl(new NetworkCallsRetrofitImpl());
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pnr_status,container,false);

    try{
        init();
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
    return view;
}

private void init() {

    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            setUrlKeysAndValues();
            ServiceCalls.getInstance().getDataFromServer(getActivity()
                    ,Utils.getInstance().buildUrl(urlKeys,urlValues),"onResponse");
        }
    });

}

public void onResponse(String response){

    String x = response;
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(x);
        String name = jsonObject.getJSONObject("train").getString("name");
        String temp = jsonObject.getJSONObject("train").getString("name");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Now my question is "have i correctly implemented that design pattern".If not,what changes i need to do.In onCreate of MainFragment Code i am hardCoding the implementation.How Code to interface design pattern could be better applied in this scenario.Thankyou.

**UPDATE**

Here 'String Callback' is just a method name to be called after receiving response.This method is written in fragment class where the view has to be updated.I am calling this method using Java Reflection.

Comment: better move this question to code review. http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Methods with callbacks should have no return type. You return null anyway, so make them void.

2) You will eventually need the response back in the UI to update your views, so You should pass the callback as a `Callback` class, not some `String callback`.

3) That private field does not need updated for every call to your methods.

4) You don't need an Activity to make a network request (back to point 2, I guess)

5) I'm pretty sure Retrofit uses annotations to handle the URL, so not sure I see the purpose of the parameter at `getDataFromServer(url)`.

---

Your updated code would look like this.

Note: This is not a showcase of "programming an interface", or really any "design pattern", it is simply "clean code" (IMHO).

Retrofit already enforces the "program an interface" pattern, anyway though the `Retrofit.create` method.

```
public class NetworkCallsRetrofitImpl implements NetworkCallsApi{

    private final Retrofit retrofit;

    public NetworkCallsRetrofitImpl() {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(StringConstants.ROOT_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    }

    public void getDataFromServer(String url, Callback<ResponseBody> cb) {
        retrofit.create(RetrofitApi.class)
            .getDataFromServer(url)
            .enqueue(cb);
    }
}
```

```
// This method seems really pointless, by the way... 
public void getDataFromServer(String url, Call<ResponseBody> callback){
    networkCallsimpl.getDataFromServer(url,callback);
}
```

```
public class StatusFragment extends Fragment implements Callback<ResponseBody> {   

    private ServiceCalls serviceCalls;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Setting the implementation
        serviceCalls = ServiceCalls.getInstance();
        serviceCalls.setNetworkCallsimpl(new NetworkCallsRetrofitImpl());
    }

    private void updateStatus() {
        serviceCalls.getDataFromServer("http://site.example/status", this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        String response = response.body().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response, TOAST.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

     @Override
     public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
         Log.e("err", t.getMessage());
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.I have updated some points in the question about the string callback and the retrofit and other interface.please have a look at it.

Comment: Using reflection is bad and I would not suggest it (unless you are unable to avoid it)

Comment: what if i want to use volley implementation instead of retrofit?

Comment: You really wouldn't mix or switch, in my opinion. Not that it can't be done. There is just no good reason to. And Volley has the concept of the RequestQueue that retrofit does not, so you would have to stick that somewhere.

Comment: And Volley's Response.Listener classes are not compatible with Retrofit's Callback class, so even if you wanted to switch, you'd need to wrap those in your own abstract callback